# Redux data not rerendering when setting value within object (Immutable.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, immutable.js

I have an immutable.js Map stored in Redux that is structured like:

```
reduxObject: {
    details: {}
    ...
    objectToChange: {
       myPosts: [{
        name: 'someName',
        link: 'someLink',
       }],
       drafts: []
    }
}
```

I am trying to append the array objectToChange.myPosts in a reducer function using

```
let temp = state.getIn([objectToChange, myPosts])
temp.push(action.payloadData)
return state.setIn([objectToChange, myPosts], temp)
```

The redux data is getting updated, however the displayed redux data  isn't getting rerendered. I was expecting the state.setIn to create a new immutable object causing react native to trigger a rerender. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time

Comment: I can't see how immutable.js is used on this. If you didn't use `fromJS` or some other method to turn that deep object into a full immutable, `myPost` is a normal object and _mutable_. That's obviously not working.
`getIn` expects a list of keys, not object references: `getIn(['objectToChange', 'myPosts')`.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround to using immutable that i'm not sure is acceptable but it works. I am now using lodash's cloneDeep function.

```
  let temp = _.cloneDeep(state)
  temp[action.payloadType][action.payloadLoc].push(action.payloadData)
  return (temp)
```

Comment: I would very much recommend to look into modern Redux with the official Redux toolkit, which takes over immutable updates and cloning for you. A reducer there would just be `state[action.payloadType][action.payloadLoc].push(action.payloadData)` and it would end up to be immutable. Please read the official Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts
This is the officially recommended approach for any Redux code you write for over two years now.

Comment: If lodash can be used on a immutable.js object, it is not correctly instantiated. If one would run `fromJS(reduxObject)`, that would likely make lodash explode... but immutable.js would work as intended

Answer (score -1):

Ok so cloneDeep was a bad workaround but i found the proper solution to the problem. I needed to return the statement like this:

```
case 'postNewItemFbData':
  let tempUpdate = state[action.payloadType][action.payloadLoc]
  tempUpdate.push(action.payloadData)
  return {
    ...state,
    [`${action.payloadType}.${action.payloadLoc}`]: tempUpdate
  }
```